# Using Google Cloud Endpoints API over local HTTP

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am using OSX. I have set up my endpoints in my development server. When I visit `localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer`, I receive this error message:

> The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause
>   problems. Learn [how to use Explorer with a local HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api).

The link instructs me to *start a Chrome session with special flags as follows*:

```
[path-to-Chrome] --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:port
```

I am confused about where to input this line? I assumed that it should be entered into the CLI, so I tried it on the terminal:

```
$ /Applications/GoogleChrome.app --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080
```

Of course, the response is this:

```
$ -bash: GoogleChrome.app: command not found
```

After some research, I found that I can launch a Chrome session using the `$ google-chrome` command, but this also failed with `-bash: google-chrome: command not found`.

I also tried to locate Chrome using `$ whereis google-chrome`, but this returns no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080`